# Degree of polynomials in vanishing ideals of varieties.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, affine-varieties

Let $\mathbb{V}\subseteq \mathbb{F}^n $ be a variety of dimension $r$ and degree $s$. What is the minimum/maximum degree of any polynomial in the vanishing  ideal $\mathbb{I}(\mathbb{V})$ of $\mathbb{V}$? Are there any known lower or upper bounds on the degree of polynomials in $\mathbb{I}(\mathbb{V})$ in terms of $r$ and $s$?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: There is certainly no upper bound: $\mathbb{I}(\mathbb{V})$ is closed under multiplication by arbitrary polynomials, so (unless it is trivial) it contains polynomials of arbitrarily high degrees.